# What is the difference between "I put a picture on/in/at the front/back of the box"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrase-usage

I have done some research and it seems that "**the front/back**" refers to either the front or back surface/space of something respectively.

So, "**put the picture on the front/back of the box**" means to stick it on the front/back surface of the box

[image]

"**put the picture in the front/back of the box**" means to put it in the front/back space of the box

[image]

It seems like we can say "**put the picture in/at the front/back of the box**" as "**in/at**" can be interchanged in this case.

So, we can not say "**sit on the front/back of the horse**" because it is impossible to do that right?

But we say "**sit on the horse**" and "**sit on horseback**".

In this case, do we say "**sit in the front/back of the horse**"?

But my thinking might be wrong.

Comment: Note that the *back* of a horse is not the same *back* that a box has - if only because it's actually located on the *top* of it...

Comment: The normal way to ride a horse is to sit on its back! It's impossible to sit **on** its front, and to be **in front of** a horse is to have its head facing you.